# Building a tree from a regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I need to build the tree representing a Java regular expression. `java.util.regex.Pattern` do the job, but its `root` field and `Node` inner class (and its subclasses) are not visible, so I can't access them. I have to write my own parser and reimplement all the parsing logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* use [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) to get at those private fields, or use an existing regex/PCRE parser: http://bkiers.github.com/PCREParser. Note that the PCREParser lib (of which I am the author) is never put to a real (unit) test: so if you're planning on using it in production code, throw some proper unit tests against it! :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I need strict compliance with the Java regex dialect. Your ANTLR-based lib, for example, doesn't match correctly the regex `"[a|]"`, interpreting `'|'` as the OR operator. Probably reflection is the only feasible solution.

Comment: @Manuel, it matches it fine (not matching it implies a mismatch-exception, or similar). True, I don't change token types of meta-chars like `|`, `*`, `+`, etc. inside character classes. This would result in much embedded code. It's trivial to walk the tree afterwards and change the types of all child-tokens of a `CHAR_CLASS` tree: the input `"[a|]"` *is* properly parsed into the tree: `^(CHAR_CLASS 'a' '|')`. Regardless, reflection might still be the better option, of course! :)